# Python - How to iterate over dictionary to get attribute-based access

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using `POST` request i recieve this one respond

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response version="1.1">
   <accommodations>
      <accommodation name="accom1">
         <concepts>
            <concept name="concept1-1">
               <boards>
                  <board name="board1-1">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
                  <board name="board1-2">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
               </boards>
            </concept>
            <concept name="concept2-1">
               <boards>
                  <board name="board2-1">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
                  <board name="board2-2">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
               </boards>
            </concept>
          </concepts>
      </accommodation>
      <accommodation name="accom2">
         <concepts>
            <concept name="concept3-1">
               <boards>
                  <board name="board3-1">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
                  <board name="board3-2">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
               </boards>
            </concept>
            <concept name="concept4-1">
               <boards>
                  <board name="board4-1">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
                  <board name="board4-2">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
               </boards>
           </concept>
         </concepts>
       </accommodation>
    </accommodations>
</response>
```

Then, using this script i convert this data into dictionary to get access to

```
attributes and put it to the database.
def etree_to_dict(t):
        d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
        children = list(t)
        if children:
                dd = defaultdict(list)
                for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
                        for k, v in dc.iteritems():
                                dd[k].append(v)
                d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}}
        if t.attrib:
                d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.iteritems())
        if t.text:
                text = t.text.strip()
                if children or t.attrib:
                        if text:
                                d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
                else:
                        d[t.tag] = text
        return d    
my_result = ET.fromstring(my_response.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
d = globalvars.etree_to_dict(my_result)
```

When i access to attribute of `accommodation`, every thing is fine:

```
my_data=d['response']['accommodations']['accommodation']
        for n in my_data.get('accommodation'):
                p = XMLData(
                        name = n.get('@name')
                )
```

But when i try to iterate over `concept` or `boards`, i've got an Error `list indices must be integers, not str`, cause after `for` loop, i've got string but not dictionary

```
for n in my_data.get('accommodation'):
  for k, v in n['concepts'].iteritems():
    print v['@name']
```

How i shouls iterate over dictionary to have attribute-based access? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `iteritems` yields (key, value) pairs that are bound to the name `v`, so `v['concept']` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i've just edite the code

Answer (score 0):

`accommodations`, `concepts` and `boards` are lists, not `dict`s. So try to iterate over them as follows:

```
for accommodation in d['response']['accommodations']:
    for concept in accommodation['concepts']:
        print concept['@name']
    for board in accommodation['boards']:
        print board['@name']
```

Comment: Updated my answer